# Laravel 500 server error on shared hosting

Tags: sql, laravel, shared-hosting

Im trying to deploy my laravel project with namecheap however I'm getting a 500 server error.I've updated the server.php and index.php to point to the correct directories but I'm still getting the error. I've checked the error.log file in the public_html directory but it doesn't give any error when loading the site. I've also double checked the .env file to make sure the correct database credentials were entered.

**index.php**

```
if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/../nue/storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require __DIR__.'/../nue/storage/framework/maintenance.php';
}
require __DIR__.'/../nameofproject/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../nameofproject/bootstrap/app.php';
```

**server.php**

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../nameofproject/public_html/index.php';
```

Comment: You shouldn't be editing the `server.php` or `index.php` files. Such configuration should be done via your `apache` or `nginx` config files.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I deploy my Laravel project in a sharedhost. These things I do

1. Copy the entire application directory (appname) inside public_html
2. Path to the domain will be "public_html/appname/public"
3. Link storage path using ssh

Answer (score 0):

If your Laravel project is installed in the webroot (assuming `public_html`), then do the following:

1. Move the contents of `public/` up one dir to the webroot.  `index.php` and `server.php` should now be in the same dir as your `.env`.
2. In `index.php`, change `../vendor/autoload.php` to just `vendor/autoload.php` and `../bootstrap/app.php` to just `bootstrap/app.php`.
3. In `server.php`, change `public/index.php` to just `index.php`.

Comment: I did some more digging and checked the error log again. I can see that the its looking for the vendor/autoload.php file in the public_html folder (PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/.../public_html/nameofproject/vendor/autoload.php'). However I have my project located outside of the public_html folder in a separate directory. Which file do I change to point it to the correct path?

Comment: "I have my project located outside of the public_html folder in a separate directory" - **What actual dir might that be?**